# Inner/Outer class obj.new

Tags: java

This is the example of member inner class that is invoked outside a class.

```
//Program of memeber inner class that is invoked outside a class

class Outer {
    private int data=10;

    class Inner {
        void msg() {
            System.out.println("Data: " + data);
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
          Outer obj=new Outer();
          Outer.Inner in = obj.new Inner();
          in.msg();
    }
}
```

Could someone explane this line of code: `Outer.Inner in = obj.new Iner()`; what does `obj.new Inner()` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that `Outer` and `Inner` are related. More specifically, you *need* an `Outer` instance in order to create an `Inner` instance.

```
Outer.Inner in = obj.new Inner();
```

creates an `Inner` instance from `obj`, an `Outer` instance. You can see that these two are related in that the `msg()` method of `in` will use `obj`'s `data` field: *`in` makes use of `obj`'s state*. If `Inner` was `static` it wouldn't have any relationship with `Outer`, so you could just use

```
Outer.Inner in = new Outer.Inner();  // no Outer instance needed
```

Of course in your case you can't simply make `Inner` static because it uses the `data` field.

Answer (score 2):

```
Outer.Inner in = obj.new Iner();
```

Using reference of `outer` object you are creating object for `Iner` class, because `Iner` is part of `Outer` class. Here is [more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).