# Getting error using nested ActionListener class for a JButton Object?

Tags: java, event-handling, actionlistener, nested-class

It's my first time trying to use action listeners and event-handling. I'm trying to create a simple GUI that has 3 buttons: `home`, `about` and `tag`. For each `JButton` I've added a listener object and created a nested class for the listener object.

```
public class interfacetest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("GUI Test");
        window.setSize(250, 100);
        window.setLocation(100, 100);

        final JButton home = new JButton("Home");
        final JButton about = new JButton("About");
        final JButton tag = new JButton("Tag");

        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        menu.add(home);
        menu.add(about);
        menu.add(tag);
        menu.setVisible(true);
        window.setJMenuBar(menu);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        home.addActionListener(handler);
        about.addActionListener(handler);
        tag.addActionListener(handler);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Here is my nested class.

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String string = "";
            if (event.getSource()==home)
                string = string.format("home: %s, event.getActionCommand()");
            else if (event.getSource()==about)
                string = string.format("about: %s, event.getActionCommand()");
            else if (event.getSource()==tag) string = string.format("tag: %s, event.getActionCommand()");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm getting the error when I'm creating a new `thehandler` object saying:** *"No enclosing instance of type interfacetest is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type interfacetest (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of interfacetest)."*

Comment: What compiler/lint produces such verbose messages?  From you post it's very difficult to deduce your class structure.  What class does your main() method belong to?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. But I've added the class in the code. Main() belongs to the: interfacetest class. Also I use eclipse.

Comment: Then your message is clear: you need an instance of an `outer` class to instantiate its `inner` class. Have a look at [Inner/Outer class obj.new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219366/inner-outer-class-obj-new).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two simple ways to fix this:

1. Make your nested class static: `private static class thehandler`.
2. Create an instance of your enclosing class: `(new interfacetest()).new thehandler()` (you will need to restructure your code probably, and you might want to keep a reference to your `interfacetest` instance.

Like this:

```
interfacetest iner = new interfacetest();
// Do things...
thehandler handler = iner.new thehandler(); // (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of interfacetest.)
```

**Explanation:** Your nested class is non-static, but you try to access it as if it is.

- If a member of a class is not static, you have to access it through an instance of the class: `classInstance.nonStaticMember` (option 2 above).
- If a member of a class is static, you can access it either way, but the correct way is through the class type: `ClassType.staticMember` (option 1 above).

In your case you are doing something like `ClassType.nonStaticMember`, or `this.nonStaticMember` ("No enclosing instance of type interfacetest is accessible").

You might also find this terminology (from the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)) useful:

> Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are called *static nested classes*. Non-static nested classes are called *inner classes*.

**Notes:**

- Call `pack()` on your `JFrame` instead of manually `setSize(...)`.
- Call `setVisible(true)` only after you made all the changes to the layout.
- When your buttons do different things, create an action listener for each one (it makes more sense).
- If your buttons do a similar thing, such as create the same panel only with a different color, create a single action listener with a constructor taking the color (make a field for it), and apply it in `actionPerformed`.
- Class names start with uppercase in Java's naming conventions.